# Which web service does Magento use to update the currency rate

Tags: magento-1.9, web-services, currency-rates

I know that Magento has the option to convert currency and I can set the cron to update the conversion rate. But what i want to know is, where does Magento get the conversion rate from? **What web service is Magento using to update the currency conversion rate?**

I need to know because I want to let my sellers know from where I am getting the conversion rate from.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses webservicex.net to pull the currency conversion rates. 
You can check that by visiting

**System->Configuration -> Currency setup -> webservicex.**

then, take a look at

**Mage_Directory_Model_Currency_Import_Webservicex**
and

**Mage_Directory_Model_Observer**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you should accept this as answer.. LOL.. :) Have a smile.

Comment: Now webservicex stopped operation. You may need to search for another solution

Answer (score 0):

By default currency rates are pulled from `webservicex.net`.
For more details look at

```
Mage_Directory_Model_Currency_Import_Webservicex
```

and

```
Mage_Directory_Model_Observer classes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 uses services defined in the Directory module that are registered in module-directory/etc/di.xml like this:

```
<type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\Config">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="servicesConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="yahoofinance" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Yahoo Finance Exchange</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\YahooFinance</item>
            </item>
            <item name="webservicex" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Webservicex</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\Webservicex</item>
            </item>
            <item name="fixerio" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Fixer.io</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```